# Can one use an SQL AND-statement in C# referencing multiple C# variables? If so, how?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to get the following code to work properly in C# so that the selection from my database will be dependent on two columns (ID and StartTime) rather than just one.

```
myUpdateData.UpdateData(dtUpdate, "SELECT EntryRecord, StartTime, EndTime, ID FROM tblTimeManagement WHERE ID = " + cmbxEmployees.SelectedIndex " AND StartTime = " + DateTime.Today);
```

This same structure has worked in another capacity without the AND-statement in another part of my program where ID is the only focus of the WHERE in the SQL statement.  Am I going about this wrong, or is this not possible in C#?

The functioning code I mentioned above is as follows:

```
myUpdateData.UpdateData(dtUpdate, "SELECT ID, FamilyName, GivenName, Address, Phone, PayRate FROM tblEmployees WHERE ID = " + int.Parse(txtFamilyName.Tag.ToString()));
```

Comment: This code is potentially susceptible to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Please use parameterized queries when constructing SQL statements.

Comment: Generally you can use AND in SQL statements however you have to apply the correct formatting, right now you're appending a DateTime object to a string and expect it to work which it won't. I highly recommend that you use [prepared statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare?view=netframework-4.8) where you don't have to handle formatting yourself.

Comment: Also, by switching to parameterized queries you will solve the issue you are currently facing (your date is not properly quoted using single quotes in your SQL statement).

Comment: Yes you can do that.  However you will be repeatedly reminded that you should be using parameters or else you're wide up to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: You probably need single quotes around your date.  As others have stated, switch to parameterized queries.  The quotes won't be needed.

Comment: Add parenthesis : WHERE (ID = " + cmbxEmployees.SelectedIndex " AND StartTime = " + DateTime.Today).  I've seen this error in the past with SQL Server and adding the parenthesis eliminated the error.

Comment: @jdweng just no.

Comment: _"Am I going about this wrong"_ - yes, for multiple reasons. First of all, you're not telling us why this doesn't work. Does it give you an error? Second, you don't show `UpdateData()`, which is probably some homegrown wrapper code around `SqlCommand` code. You should not use such wrappers, as they actively harm the flexibility the database API offers you. Thirdly, as others have told you, you should not use string concatenation for database queries, but parameterized queries.

Comment: @CodeCaster: You can use wrappers if they do the right thing (i.e. parameterization).  Dapper does this, for example.

Comment: @Robert exactly. Therefore the OP should show that wrapper, so we can advise them how to modify it so it does the right thing, as currently it doesn't.

Comment: @CodeCaster : As I said parenthesis are needed and I have done it in the past.

Comment: @jdweng no, parentheses around multiple WHERE conditions are NOT needed in SQL, and still won't make this query work, because the error is in missing quotes. See also [the docs for MSSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). They _could_ be needed if you're mixing AND and OR conditions, because of operator precedence. But that's not what you meant, and not the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I think one way that you should familiarize yourself with, as a new developer, is `string.Format`.

**DISCLAIMER** - It is true that you should use [commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand) and [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter) when you are update a SQL table, BUT when all of the code is internal and risk is low ---

I have use `string.Format` to bring various data into a SQL statement (select, insert, update, delete)

Here is a sample using your query.

```
var query = string.Format(@"SELECT 
                            EntryRecord, StartTime, EndTime, ID 
                            FROM 
                            tblTimeManagement 
                            WHERE 
                            ID = '{0}' AND StartTime = '{1:yyyy-MM-dd}'", 
                      cmbxEmployees.SelectedIndex, DateTime.Now);
```

The static function `string.Format` has multiple overloads, but in this case we are using this one:

```
string Format(string format, params object[] args)
```

It takes a template for your string and then any array of objects.  Within the `format` parameter, your string will contain a set of tokens that are placeholder for your various values (SelectedIndex, Current Time, etc).  They are represented as integers wrapped with braces, i.e.: (`{0}`, `{1}`).  You must begin from zero, then onward sequentially based on how many variables you have.

You can also format the variables as they are parsed into your query.  I have demonstrated this with the datetime format in the second variable placeholder (`{1:yyyy-MM-dd}`).

more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format

Comment: No offense, but in the time you typed the five paragraphs of `string.Format()` explanation you could've written up a parameterized query example.

Comment: OP: Notice the use of single quotes around the date.

Comment: @CodeCaster: The OP is using a function called UpdateData that we know nothing about.

Comment: @Robert I know, and therefore the question should not be answered as-is. It is incomplete. "How to shoot myself in the foot" should not be answered with "With this loaded pistol, which is safe as long as you know how to use it".

Comment: @CodeCaster: Well, we don't really know the constrains placed on the OP.  This decision is like any other; you weigh the benefits and risks, and take your chances.

Comment: @Glenn Ferrie.  Thanks so much for the articulate example and suggestions.